# Task jettyRunWar with slf4j and log4j results in an error. How can I use log4j for logging?

Tags: gradle, log4j, jetty, slf4j

I am working on a new project and attempting to use Gradle for the first time. The application is a web application so I have configured the `war` and `jetty` plugins at the top of my `gradle.build`:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
```

In my code I program to the [Apache Commons Logging API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) for logging. One of my dependencies ([OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Home)) uses the [SLF4J API](http://www.slf4j.org/) for its logging. I am most familiar with [log4j 1.2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) for the actual logging configuration, so that is what I want to use to actually perform the logging.

To configure these dependencies I have the following in my `gradle.build` file:

```
// Logging API
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.21'
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version: '1.7.21'

// Logging at runtime
runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.21'
runtime group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
```

When I run my application using the command `gradle jettyRunWar` and the servlet executes which tries to log something I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at sso.HomePageServlet.<clinit>(HomePageServlet.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND bound slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:54)
    ... 33 more
```

The error is obviously that `log4j-over-slf4j.jar` is in the classpath as well. My application does not list this. Using `gradle dependencies --configuration runtime` does not list this .jar file either. The only place this .jar exists is in the `gradle\lib` directory. Is it possible that Gradle is including its own classpath when launching Jetty?

Is there any way to prevent this?

The solution outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7982507/3154) does not seem to work.

`gradle -v` shows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.14.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-07-18 06:38:37 UTC
Revision:     d9e2113d9fb05a5caabba61798bdb8dfdca83719

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_45 (Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

Comment: I don't know the answer but this thread - https://discuss.gradle.org/t/slf4j-detected-both-log4j-over-slf4j-jar-and-bound-slf4j-log4j12-jar-on-the-class-path/14067 - references an issue that appears to be open - https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-897 . Some of the comments might have a workaround.

Comment: @MichaelEaster Thanks so much for that link. I am sure it is the same issue. Unfortunately the only real suggested workaround (write your own plugin) is a bit beyond my Gradle knowledge right now. I will wait to see if anybody else responds and just keep going with logback on my sample project for now.

Answer (score 4):

Just after posting my question I saw that [Gradle 3.0](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/releases/tag/v3.0.0) was released. In the release notes it says that the `jetty` plugin has been deprecated and that one should use [`Gretty`](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty).

Upgrading to Gradle 3.0 and switching to using `Gretty` fixed the problem.

The fact that the `jetty` plugin includes Gradle's classpath in your webapps' runtime path is a problem with the way the `jetty` plugin works and it looks like it will not be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few years and versions too late, but just for complete closure I confirm that internal gradle logging is interfering.  My log includes the following:

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/**/.gradle/**/gradle-2.14.1/lib/gradle-logging-2.14.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/**/build/tmp/jettyRunWar/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

Where **gradle-logging-2.14.1.jar** contains the offending **org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory** class.

#### Work Around

Since we're dealing with a legacy monolithic multi-project build, we're just not ready to bump the gradle version up (leave well enough alone).  We encountered this problem when the dependency **slf4j-log4j12** was update from version **1.7.2** to **1.7.25** (we didn't leave well enough alone).  The resolution, for us, was to bump that back down to version **1.7.13**, just before the check was added.